# Trying to see how many orders by year/month for customers based on itemised list of orders

Tags: mysql

I have a simple database table listing customerID and orderDate. I would like to produce a grid showing how many orders each customer has placed month between a date range

e.g.

```
customerID  orderDate
1           2015-01-15
1           2015-01-25
1           2015-02-01
1           2015-04-05
2           2015-02-15
2           2015-02-25
2           2015-03-01
2           2015-03-05
3           2015-02-01
3           2015-05-08
```

And then what I am looking for is:

```
customerID  jan2015 feb2015 mar2015 apr2015 may2015
1           2       1       0       1       0
2           0       2       2       0       0
3           0       1       0       0       1
```

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, they can

Comment: @Strawberry If they've ordered 20 on Jan 1st and 5 on January 10th then I just want to see 25 under the jan2015 column

Comment: @Strawberry in this table there is no key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this. MySQL has several helpful [date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) which you can use for queries like this. In this example, I would take note of the `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` functions. Then you can write conditional statements for each column the count the rows that occur in each month and year, like this:

```
SELECT customer, 
  SUM(MONTH(orderDate) = 1 AND YEAR(orderDate) = 2015) AS jan2015,
  SUM(MONTH(orderDate) = 2 AND YEAR(orderDate) = 2015) AS feb2015,
  SUM(MONTH(orderDate) = 3 AND YEAR(orderDate) = 2015) AS mar2015,
  SUM(MONTH(orderDate) = 4 AND YEAR(orderDate) = 2015) AS apr2015,
  SUM(MONTH(orderDate) = 5 AND YEAR(orderDate) = 2015) AS may2015
FROM orders
GROUP BY customer;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b1dae/1) example.

Comment: @Code-Monk I don't understand the question. More months how?

Comment: i mean, will it work for july,august and rest of the months of the year?

Comment: @Code-Monk Yes, you'll just have to add to the select statement and make sure you set the appropriate condition for `MONTH(orderDate) = ?`